# Event Listener and Debug Toolbar

Tags: php, symfony, propel, event-listener

when i have active the event listener my debug toolbar collapse. here is the code of my event listener.

```
class PermisoListener {

private $container;

public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container = null) {
    $this->container = $container;
}

public function onKernelRequest(GetResponseEvent $event) {
    $request = $this->container->get('request');
    $ruta = $request->get('_route');
    if ($this->container->get('security.context')->isGranted('ROLE_USUARIO')) {
        $usuario = $this->container->get('security.context')->getToken()->getUser();
        $horario = HorarioQuery::create()
                ->filterByDiaId(date('N'))
                ->useUsuarioHorarioQuery()
                ->filterByUsuarioId($usuario->getId())
                ->endUse()
                ->findOne();
        if ((!$horario == null) && (date('Hi') >= $horario->getHoraInicio('Hi') ) && (date('Hi') <= $horario->getHoraFin('Hi') )) {
            $menus = MenuQuery::create()
                    ->usePerfilMenuQuery()
                    ->usePerfilQuery()
                    ->useUsuarioPerfilQuery()
                    ->filterByUsuarioId($usuario->getId())
                    ->endUse()
                    ->endUse()
                    ->endUse()
                    ->filterByRuta($ruta)
                    ->findOne();
            if ($menus != null || $ruta == '' || $ruta == 'usuario_bitacora_login' || $ruta == 'pagina_inicio' || $ruta == '_pagina_inicio' || $ruta == 'usuario_bitacora_logout') {
                return;
            } else {

                $event->setResponse($this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('VelfasaSoporteBundle:Default:portada.html.twig'));
            }
        } else {
            $bitacora = new Bitacora();
            $bitacora->setUsuarioId($usuario->getId());
            $bitacora->setDescripcion('Error, Horario de trabajo no válido ');
            $bitacora->setFechaYHora(date('Y-m-d H:i:s'));
            $bitacora->setDireccion($this->container->get('request')->getClientIp());
            $bitacora->setEstado(0);
            $bitacora->save();
            $this->container->get("request")->getSession()->invalidate();
            $this->container->get("security.context")->setToken(null);
            $event->setResponse($this->container->get('templating')->renderResponse('::error.html.twig', array('error' => 'Error, inicio de sesion en hora no laboral')));
        }
    }else{
        return;
    }
}
```

}

like you can see on the code when doesnt happen anything I send an empty return. And everything is ok, but this dont show the Symfony2 debug toolbar and I really need that.

Please help

Answer (score 1):

In order to see `Symfony2` debug bar you have to return a response containing the `<body>` Tag.

The Web Profiler searches for the `<body>` tag of a response (usually from a template) and updates it to include the profiler.

So in your controller, the response is what you return from the action methods:

- An `array` which populated a pre-determined template.
- A `Response` object which contains HTML text

Either of these can include a body tag which the Web Profiler event listener will modify.

Replace each `return;` with `return new Response('<body></body>');`

Comment: Can you say me how please i dont find that.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to use the "return;" where the route caught by the event listener is "_wdt"